# Using JavaScript to create a <script src=...> element breaks the API that I'm trying to use

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

At the top of one of my HTML files there is this line:

```
<script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=apikey"></script>
```

This API key is currently hard-coded into the file, and I want to instead use a config option defined in a .cfg file elsewhere. However, I can't get any sort of variable into the src attribute of the script element.

I have tried:

```
<script>
    document.createElement('script')).src='//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=apikeybutvariable'; 
</script>
```

and

```
<script>
  $('<script>').attr({
    src: '//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=apikeybutvariable',
    type: 'text/javascript'}).appendTo('body')
</script>
```

When I try either of these the next script element can't see the content defined by the Google Maps JS API.
What's going on here, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you’re trying to use the functionality defined in the JavaScript file right after it won’t work. It hasn’t been loaded yet. JavaScript is synchronous: any modification to the DOM is only acted upon by the browser after your code finishes. This means loading the file happens only after your code finishes and only after it has been loaded you can use what’s defined in it. The loading also takes time and appending it to the body means it’s loaded at the end while your other code is before it.

Either use a ready made dynamic loader or attach an event to the script tag to call a function after it has been loaded. Then you know when it’s available for use.

Comment: `any modification to the DOM is put into a queue and only done after your code finishes.` that’s not true, if you append an element tongue DOM and in the same _code_ search for that element, then you will find that element, also other changes to elements (attrs, props, ...) are applied immediately. That’s e.g. one reasons why it might be better to build a large table while it is not attached to the DOM.

Comment: @t.niese I think I have a confusing word choice. What I meant is that the browser will not handle/render the changes immediately. I’ll edit it to be clearer

Answer (score 0):

If what you mean is regarding not able to visit the API of google map from the 'next script'. Then this is the answer you can refer to.

Javascript script, no matter inline script or external script ( such as the google map API), they execute as the order they placed in the html document usually. The order does not always matter, but it does when there is dependency exists. If this is the problem in your code,  you have to do it to ensure the 'next script' is actually executed after the google map script got loaded and executed already. There are lots of methods you can take to achieve this, e.d. export an init function that startup the code in 'next script', and call the function when received [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) event.

Answer (score -1):

Try out external script element.. it worked for me

**.html file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis:400,700" rel="stylesheet"/>
   </head>
   <body>
      <script>
         // Create a request variable and assign a new XMLHttpRequest object to it.
         var request = new XMLHttpRequest()

         // Open a new connection, using the GET request on the URL endpoint
         request.open('GET', 'https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/films', true)

         request.onload = function() {
         // Begin accessing JSON data here
         }

         // Send request
         request.send()
      </script>
   </body>
```

Comment: I am not requesting anything from the URL. From what I understand I am simply appending the javascript at that URL to the top of my page. I don't see how I can make a http get request work this way.